# How do I test a viewModelScope controlled SharedFlow?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-viewmodel, kotlin-coroutines

I have a `SharedFlow`. When the `ViewModel` is created, I change the value to `Val1`. After that, I use the `viewModelScope` to make some fake delay of `3 seconds` and then change the value to `Val2`.

```kotlin
class MyViewModel : ViewModel() {

    val x = MutableSharedFlow<String>()

    init {
        x.tryEmit("Val1")
        viewModelScope.launch {
            delay(3000)
            x.tryEmit("Val2")
        }
    }
}
```

**Question**

1. How do I test the initial value is `Val1`?
2. How do I test if the value has changed to `Val2` after delay?

Comment: If you don't have any replay buffer, nobody will ever be able to get this initial value, because it will be emitted and lost before subscribers have a chance to start collecting the shared flow

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution:

It's as simple as setting the Main dispatcher to `TestCoroutineDispatcher`.

```
@ExperimentalCoroutinesApi
class CoroutineMainExtension : BeforeEachCallback, AfterEachCallback {
    val dispatcher = TestCoroutineDispatcher()
    override fun beforeEach(context: ExtensionContext?) {
        Dispatchers.setMain(dispatcher)
    }

    override fun afterEach(context: ExtensionContext?) {
        Dispatchers.resetMain()
        dispatcher.cleanupTestCoroutines()
    }
}
```

and use it like this:

`@ExtendWith(CoroutineMainExtension::class)`

Answer (score -1):

To test it, you need a way to inject your testing context. It is typically done by setting it as Dispatchers.Main.

Then the easy path is to use `MutableStateFlow` instead of `MutableSharedFlow`. Here is an example:

```kotlin
class MyViewModel : ViewModel() {

    val x = MutableStateFlow("Val1")

    init {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            delay(3000)
            x.tryEmit("Val2")
        }
    }
}

class MyViewModelTests {
    private val testDispatcher = TestCoroutineDispatcher()

    @Before
    fun setUp() {
        Dispatchers.setMain(testDispatcher)
    }

    @Test
    fun test() = runBlocking {
        // given
        val myViewModel = MyViewModel()

        // then
        assertEquals("Val1", myViewModel.x.value)

        // when
        testDispatcher.advanceTimeBy(3000)

        // then
        assertEquals("Val2", myViewModel.x.value)
    }
}
```

If you want to test `MutableSharedFlow`, you should better move your logic from the constructor to some function, like `onCreate`. Then you should collect and observe how your values change. Here is an example (we could make a better one with some testing library like Turbine):

```kotlin
class MyViewModel : ViewModel() {

    val x = MutableSharedFlow<String>()

     fun onCreate() {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            x.emit("Val1")
            delay(3000)
            x.emit("Val2")
        }
    }
}

class MyViewModelTests {
    private val testDispatcher = TestCoroutineDispatcher()

    @Before
    fun setUp() {
        Dispatchers.setMain(testDispatcher)
    }

    @Test
    fun test() = runBlocking {
        // given
        val myViewModel = MyViewModel()
        var xChangeHistory = mapOf<Long, String>()
        myViewModel.viewModelScope.launch {
            myViewModel.x.collect {
                xChangeHistory += testDispatcher.currentTime to it
            }
        }

        // then
        myViewModel.onCreate()
        testDispatcher.advanceUntilIdle()

        // then
        assertEquals(mapOf(0L to "Val1", 3000L to "Val2"), xChangeHistory)
    }
}
```

Comment: I am aware of how to test a StateFlow. The question is how do I do it with `SharedFlow`?

Comment: Isn't the second part providing you an answer? If you want to keep this function as the constructor, set the `replay` parameter on `SharedFlow` to 1, and then testing will be possible.

Comment: I am sorry. I won't be able to move my logic from `init` block to a method.